# Converting a Windows .cpp file for Unix system?

Tags: windows, unix, copy-paste, vi

I have a .cpp file that I wrote on my Windows 8 computer and I am trying to paste its code into my schools Unix based system via Putty SSH client. The editor that is used on the Unix machines is the Vi editor. When I copy all the code from my .cpp file in my Windows computer and right click on the Vi editor and paste, the code shows up but its all over place and I can't even read it(I am pretty sure it wouldn't compile either). Is there a way to fix it so the code maintains its formatting in the Vi editor ? Thanks for any help !

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/400012/23461

Comment: @ta.speot.is that approach didnt work

Comment: better use online converters..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is usually a unix utility called dos2unix and one called unix2dos which will convert your file to dos or unix format.

If you have those it should just be a matter of:

```
dos2unix myfile.cpp myfile.cpp
```

Also, instead of pasting it into your editor try using pscp to copy the file to your target machine.

```
pscp myfile myname@hostname:/mydirectory/myfile
```

Comment: for the pscp command, where should my Windows .cpp file should be for Putty(or VI ?) to find it ?

Comment: pscp is a command you run from a dos or cmd window.  Put it on your path and just run it from wherever the files are.  pscp comes with putty.

Comment: Thanks! I used notepad++ to convert to Unix and pscp command to copy/paste. Everything showed up in original formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must be getting beaten by the difference in the line endings of windows and unix.
You can try using editor like Notepad++ and save the file on windows.
Open the file in Noteapd++ and Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX Format and save